# Unable to update views through data binding on Android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I was trying to migrate from ButterKnife to Android data binding.

When using ButterKnife (which is working perfectly fine):

```
// Called after a network call
public void updateView(MyAdapter adapter, String title) {
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Using Android data binding:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    binding.toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name); // this works
    return binding.getRoot();
}

// Called after a network call
public void updateView(MyAdapter adapter, String title) {
    binding.toolbar.setTitle(title);
    binding.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

After calling `updateView` on the later code, the screen goes blank.
I debugged to find out that **view remains attached** to the Fragment.

Also, if I am updating something inside `onCreateView` then that **works**.

Is there anything am I doing wrong?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/default_nav_icon_back"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Could you upload full source code?

Comment: There is nothing obvious in the code that you supplied. In this case, you are only using data binding to get the views, so it isn't doing any work after the first binding. Is butterknife doing anything for you that you didn't mention during the update.